# Eclipse-RCP disabling creation of navigation history

Tags: editor, eclipse-rcp

There is a following problem: I am creating an editor, which EditorInput contains pretty big object. After creating couple of such editors I've got OutOfMemoryError. Heap memory analyzer showed, that there are 3 objects of type EditorHistoryItem, which take around 80,8% of the heap space. (I think, that I've even closed previous editors, but they are still in the memory).

I think, that those EditorHistoryItems-s are related to navigation history construction in eclipse. So, can I disable navigation history? Or what would be other correct way to dispose large EditorInput or EditorPart, without closing an editor?

Any advices would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, make your object smaller. I'm pretty sure it's not neccessary to load several Megabytes of objects. Why don't you load a pretty small object as your IEditorInput implementation when opening an editor and loading/unloading additional objects based on user-interaction (activating the Editor-Part, several tabls, pressing a button, ...) lazily.

You have a pretty good control about getting notified if the user activates an editor, changing the page (when using MultipageEditor) or other events where you can load or unload objects to minimize the footprint of your heap. There is a absolutely no need to have a big IEditorInput object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've refactored EditorInput and removed big object. It definitely resolves problem with history, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what editor functions you're using, Eclipse can have up to 5 copies of your `IEditorInput` in memory.

While this works great for < 1,000 line Java classes, you run out of memory when editing larger files.

Take a look at the source code for `FileEditorInput`, and see if you can write your own version implementing the `IEditorInput` interface that keeps most of your file on disk and just reads parts of the file.

Worst case, you'll have to write your own Eclipse editor.

Comment: I probably haven't described problem well - I already have my own editor, which extends EditorPart and thus I have an EditorInput object, which implements IEditorInput. When my editor is opened object of type EditorHistoryItem with my EditorInput inside is created. I assume it is done to support navigation possibility between editors. But I don't need it and want to disable this possibility not to keep my EditorInput in memory.

Comment: @Alexander Gavrilov: I understand what you're asking. But, unless you want to rewrite the entire Eclipse editor class library, you're limited to manipulating IEditorInput.